# break long lines in markdown code

Tags: markdown

I'm using the original-flavored markdown as described [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

I'm wondering if it's possible to **break a long line in markdown code while resulting in no syntactic effect**. (In other languages, for instance shell scripts and C, `\` would be used to continue onto the next line.) I'm asking this because newlines sometimes break the syntax, as in

```
[StackOverflow]
(http://stackoverflow.com)
```

This would end up as "[StackOverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com)" in the actual html rather than a hyperlink, since newline is interpreted as whitespace, and whitespace is not allowed between `]` and `(` in the `[text](url)` syntax for links.

Comment: You could try breaking the line _before_ the critical `](`.  It works for me, though I'm using doxygen to parse original-flavoured markdown.

Comment: @Cheeseminer Well... Great idea, although not particularly beautiful, and introduces one extra whitespace in the linked text. Btw, thank you for the workaround.

Comment: I wonder the same thing - one ends up with huge lines in the Readme.md for instance which is not exactly good coding style (readme's are diff'd too)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D If your URI is longer than 80 characters, you are screwed anyway, so nowadays I treat Markdown as prose and don't do line breaks anymore. Just use `--word-diff`.

Answer (score 55):

If you'd like to have line breaks in the code, then, as comments tell, use the line breaks inside either the text part, or inside the url part: you can actually do this

```
[StackOverflow](
http://stackoverflow.com)
```

And while the result would have the extra whitespace inside the `href`, it would still work, so no worries. This works also for spreading long links over multiple lines

```
[StackOverflow interesting discussion](
    http://stackoverflow.com/this/discussion/has/a/very/
very/very/very/long/long/long/title/title/title
```

Be sure to not let any leading whitespace on lines that start within the URL (here the last line). (only the first line break works with GitHub-flavored markdown, because GitHub treats the line breaks as whitespace).

However, if the goal is to make links more readable, I would recommend to use the link references, so you could place the actual hrefs anywhere in your document and have short and readable link titles in the text:

```
[StackOverflow][]

[StackOverflow]: http://stackoverflow.com
```

or

```
[StackOverflow][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com
```

Note that you can place the reference anywhere: it is often rather readable and easy to maintain when all the references are placed at the bottom of the readme.

Also, this method would allow you to add `title` attribute to links, if you'd need them:

```
[StackOverflow][]

[StackOverflow]: http://stackoverflow.com (Here is this link's title!)
```

Comment: I'm aware of link references, but I never really use them because jumping back and forth disrupts the workflow (if you want a nice document you really should put the references in some central place; or at least one central place for each section, for instance). Unless you have an editor that automatically handle references for you.

Comment: Anyway, in the end I decided that I wouldn't line-break my Markdown documents. That makes diffing a hell lot easier.

Comment: Well, line breaking does make diffs easier to read, because changing one word in one sentence does not result in an entire paragraph (if on a single line) appear as changed. Regarding jumping back and forth, it can be avoided with multiple tabs, one open at the file's end. However, it still is inconvenient to maintain the links at two places, because then one has to scan the accumulated links for finding the one to edit.

Comment: Well, [`formd`](https://github.com/drbunsen/formd) is a tool for switching between inline and referenced links.

Comment: I've tried the first example and it works on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/hashlash/755fafeb1c3003ca95757db71da891fb), but the second one won't work

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with code blocks.

Answer (score 10):

Adding on to [@kizu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27071588/384954), another type of link is a ["shortcut reference link"](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.5/#shortcut-reference-link), which is even fewer characters, and in my opinion, looks nicer.

They look like this:

```
Here's a link to [Stack Overflow]. You should be able to find an
answer there. If not, let me know.

[Stack Overflow]: https://stackoverflow.com

For additional information, check out [this answer].

[this answer]:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956334/384954
```

*renders as follows*

Here's a link to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). You should be able to find an
answer there. If not, let me know.

For additional information, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956334/384954).

Comment: So.... how do we break long URLs in the source of our markdown? Just don't, and override the lint rule, instead?